# Do I need to upgrade to get iTunes 10, or can OS X 10.4.11 run it?

Tags: itunes, upgrade, macos

So, I have an old iBook G4 running OS X 10.4.11 (It was a gift for Christmas.) and when I went to download some of my iTunes purchases to my computer, I got this (Basically, it didn't say "What's New in iTunes 10.3", just "What's New in iTunes"):

[image: itunes]

(Sorry, forgot this first time around :P)

I was reading over [this](http://store.apple.com/us/question/answers/product/MC573Z/A/i-have-a-imac-os-x-10411-what-can-i-upgrade-to/QD27H7JPTJ7FYUDAJ) and it looks like Snow Leopard can be installed on my system (can anyone confirm this and what would be the pros/cons of it) and that iTunes would work on that.

However, unless it is something that will improve performance or the like, I really don't want to have to pay $20 for the upgrade disks.

Can I download/install iTunes 10 onto my G4 and will it run without turning my system into a pig in treacle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your iBook G4 can not run Snow Leopard, because of PowerPC G4 chip inside. Snow Leopard require an Intel chip. You can get iTunes 10 to work on your computer, just upgrade to Mac OS X 10.5 (eBay or so... buy full retail version, not gray discs).

Comment: OUCH! Seriously, $50+ for it. Sorry Apple, I can't afford that. (Amazon and ebay both. Best I saw was $40-ish on an auction.)